# Java REGEX Operator precedence

Tags: java, regex

I have a few strings:

```
john doe happy
george smith is happy
```

Here's my Regular Expression:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+) (is happy|happy)
```

I need group 1 to always be a name like "john doe" or "george smith"

I need group 2 to always be either "happy" or "is happy"

Right now, "george smith is happy" always matches up to  "george smith is" and "happy" ... when I really want it to be "george smith" and "is happy"

How do I make "is happy" have precedence over "happy"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` is greedy, meaning that it will match as many characters as possible, so you will never match `is happy` with your regex as it is written.  You can change this to a lazy match by changing it to `+?`, which matches as few characters as possible (still one or more):

```
([a-zA-Z ]+?) (is happy|happy)
```